# How to compare everything in 2 strings except the last 12 digits

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I want to check an arbitrary number of strings for similarity except for the last 12 characters. Like this

these 2 are considered similar

CXS101289_LL_20_P11_101029080840/

CXS101289_LL_20_P11_101105125656/

**and these 2**

CXS101289_LLV_IC_10_P163_110121114144/

CXS101289_LLV_IC_10_P163_110124114042/

**but these aren't**

**these 2**

CXS101289_LL_20_P11_101029080840/

CXS101289_LL_21_P11_101105125656/

**and these 2**

CXS101289_LLV_IC_10_P162_110121114144/

CXS101289_LLV_IC_10_P163_110124114042/

So as you can see the string always ends with 12 digits that represents the date. So I want to compare everything in the string uptil the last 12 characters of it, how can I do this in a simple method?

You can assume that I store all strings to compare in an array like this

```
var allStringsToCompare = ["CXS101289_LLV_IC_10_P162_110121114144","CXS101289_LLV_IC_10_P163_110124114042","CXS101289_LL_21_P11_101105125656"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use String.slice():

```
"CXS101289_LL_20_P11_101029080840/".slice(0, -12);
```

so:

```
var resultArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < allStringsToCompare.length; i++) {
    resultArray.push(allStringsToCompare[i].slice(0, -12));
}
```

or alternatively (if you want to change `allStringsToCompare` in place):

```
for (var i = 0; i < allStringsToCompare.length; i++) {
    allStringsToCompare[i] = allStringsToCompare[i].slice(0, -12));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [substring](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/substrin.htm) function of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the appropriate substrings:

```
string.substr(0, string.length - 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be important to know where and how the strings are different.  I wrote a fuzzy string comparison code in JavaScript to handle tasks just like this.  The specific logic is the charcomp function of http://prettydiff.com/lib/diffview.js

The fuzzy string comparison looks for equality between two strings.  The moment the two strings are not equal a wrapper is applied to show where the strings stop being identical.  Some advanced algorithmic logic is applied to determine the next available character that is present in both strings at which point the wrapper is terminated.  This logic is repeated for the extent of both strings.

You can see it in action using the [Pretty Diff](http://prettydiff.com/?l=text) tool directly.  The final 12 characters will show as a difference, or you can clip these characters off using the substring method as others have suggested.  You would use this method as:

```
input.substring(0, input.length - 12);
```